# Running long operations in a class library and reporting progress back

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

My application connects to a SQL database, returns all rows from a table, and then loops over each row and performs some processing.

If this were a graphical Forms application, I would consider doing the above in a BackgroundWorker so that the UI is not held up, and report progress or support cancellation from within the BackgroundWorker.

As I may be doing the same/similar operations in lots of apps, I would like to package the SQL work into a class library and call it from my other apps.

I understand I could potentially use BackgroundWorkers within a class library too, but how do I link the UI and the call to the library? How can I still send down cancellation requests, or report progress back up?  Or is this not the correct route at all?

Comment: The BackgroundWorker gets the context of the thread that it was started in and uses that to perform synchronization with that thread. Thus it is automatically linking itself to the UI (even though it's in a separate class) as long as you start it from the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use `BackgroundWorker` in a class library, it feels like an odd use for it, since it's primarily designed as a supplement-component for UIs.  You could manage threads directly too, but either way, you still need to come up with some way to communicate progress and allow for cancellation.  While you are obviously free to create your own pattern for that, there are basically [three standard patterns for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/).

Unless you really need the lower level control of `IAsyncResult`, the far-and-away most popular pattern everyone is using these days is TAP (Task/Async/Await).  When using TAP, there is a standard way to provide progress and cancellation.  See the the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) for more info on both of those (there's sections in that document for both of those topics).